# How to implement CSS sprite background into existing JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, background-image, sprite

I would like to add a sprite image to an existing button which previously used its own image "play.png" which I replaced with "spacer.png" (this item is already set to a fixed soze of 30x35pixels in the css). Goal is to save http requests by combining all such <kbd>play</kbd>/<kbd>pause</kbd>/ <kbd>next</kbd>/<kbd>previous</kbd> buttons to go into one singular sprite.png file.

**GIVEN, EXISTING CODE:**

```
var $backBtn = $("<img src='" + LIGHTBOX_PATH + "spacer.png' id='back-btn'/>");
$backBtn.css({opacity:BUTTON_OPACITY}).hover(buttonOver, buttonOut);
```

**I ADDED:**

```
#back-btn{
    background: url(http://website.bla/sprite.png) no-repeat -770px -550px) #F00;
    float:left;
}
```

**Why does the sprite image not show up?**  Even the background is not `F00` colored nothing appears there... Only changing the float does have effect meaning that the id does match the `#back-btn` so its something else... any ideas'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your styles in a CSS file except when absolutely necessary (i.e. changing opacity with Javascript). Add a CSS file to your website (or use an existing file if you have one), and add the following declaration:

```
#back-btn {
  float: left;
  background: url(http://website.org/sprite.png) no-repeat -770px -550px;
}
```

Comment: @ddagradi Thanks +1 updates my question, it does not work yet... piculiar... any advise why? thank you!

Comment: Can you post a demo of your code online somewhere so we can see how it's all working together?

Comment: currently I have commented out rules 137 and 143 and am trying to see hwo text arrows work, but I prefer to have the sprite working...

Comment: Try using a `div`, not a `p`. Make sure to set the width and height on your `div`.

Comment: Thanks for your advise @ddagradi, have implemented divs, removed p, everything works except background sprite! Even after removing the little error that is currently in your answer (I believe you have one `)` too much. But still no background sprite showing up... strange!? what else could I try?

Comment: Works now! it was the `)` extra Thanks very much, I accepted your answer. Bravo to us! :)